# Blazor open new tab/window using JSRuntime

Tags: c#, safari, blazor

I implemented opening a new tab/window from C# using the JSRuntime. It works fine on the desktop, but when using safari on the phone it doesn't do anything: the new tab fails to open on mobile devices.

Any one has had any luck getting this to work?

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("open", url, "_blank");
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Could you explain what happens, or not?

Comment: The new tab fails to open on mobile devices (I am trying it on iPhone safari, chrome and brave browsers)

Comment: Update: Chrome is working to open new tabs on iPhone, safari does not.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Add a javascript method to open the URL in another tab and call that method using JsRuntime.

If you use `window.open()` js method it wont work on all browsers so need to dynamically create an `a` element and raise a click event on it.

See below:

```js
window.NavigateTo = (url) => {
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.target = '_blank';
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  link.remove();
}
```

Comment: Creative solution however it still not working when trying it on mobile devices. I tried it on iPhone safari, chrome, brave and still not opening on another tab. It just doesnt do anything.

Comment: What's not working, try to check what part of the code fails, for example, put an alert in the method and see if the method is hit or not?